# getting pls-00103 error

Tags: sql, oracle

//this is my create table code and title is varchar2(30)

```
create table ratings(title references game(title)on delete cascade primary key,
steam integer,
ign integer);
```

//my stored procedure code which i'm trying to executing in sqlplus

```
create or replace procedure databas(title varchar2(20),steam number,ign number)
as
declare abc varchar2(20);
stored number;
begin
    update ratings 
    set ratings.steam=databas.steam,
        ratings.ign=databas.ign  
    where ratings.title=databas.title;
End;
/
```

but i'm getting error pls-00103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors in your procedure:

1) You don't need to specify the length `(20)`of the `VARCHAR2` that you are passing into. PL/SQL is intelligent enough to figure it out itself.

2) You do not need a `DECLARE` for a named procedure. `DECLARE` is only used for an anonymous block.

```
create or replace procedure databas(title varchar2, steam number, ign number)
as
begin
    update ratings 
      set ratings.steam=databas.steam,
          ratings.ign=databas.ign  
      where ratings.title=databas.title;
End;
/`
```

3) Your local variables `abc` and `stored` aren't used and therefore redundant in this example.

Comment: I’m glad to hear! You may want to mark the answer as answered for future readers of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect:

```
create or replace procedure databas (
    in_title varchar2(20),
    in_steam number,
    in_ign number
)
as
    abc varchar2(20);  -- not used
    stored number;     -- not used
begin
    update ratings
        set steam = in_steam,
            ign = in_ign
    where title = in_title;
End;
```

/

Comment: error i'm getting is :- PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
         one of the following:
         begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
         null pragma raise return select update while with
         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         <a bind variable> << close current delete fetch lock insert
         open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge
         pipe

Comment: `declare` section is implicit for stored procedures

Comment: @SumanthMylar . . . It is not obvious what in this code would be causing that error.

Comment: I changed varchar2(20) too varchar2 and didn't declare ABC and stored procedure as I'm not going to use it and it worked!!!!!!   Thanks for the help sir!!!